# Remove a folder from TFS after it is checked into TFS Server

Tags: tfs

I have a solution  that I checked-in incorrectly the packages folder which I shouldn't have -  its in Change set details, now can I change the Change set to eliminate this folder from it? or can I delete it form the source control without deleting it locally? and I want another solution also - how can I set this folder to be not part of the checkins for any future checkins? Thanks a lot any help please - thank you.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for source control?

Answer (score 0):

If want to permanently delete version-controlled files, [tf destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops) should help you.

If you just want to delete the folder from server, you can go to **Files** tab, and find the folder to delete it. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

You can also customize which files are ignored by version control by placing text file called **.tfignore** in the folder where you want rules to apply. The effects of the .tfignore file are recursive. Check the following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control

Comment: Two issues with this answer: 1) You're assuming TFVC, which is not necessarily the case and would be a different answer entirely. 2) You can absolutely permanently delete something from existing TFVC changesets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=azure-devops

Comment: Yes, I was assuming TFVC, as he said "changeset", and thanks for indicate the "destory" command, you are correct, if want to permanently delete version-controlled files, tf destroy command would achieve it, I will modify this answer.